# Why is the current limited to 20mA when there are LED but 8.04 amps without?

Tags: voltage, resistance

**NOTE: I HAVE ELECTRON FLOW ON INSTEAD OF CONVENTIONAL FLOW ON PURPOSE**

So I was making a circuit and it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see `8.04A` are flowing. That is normal with internal resistance of the battery and the small resistance of the wire.

But when I add three LEDs:

[image]

The current is instantly `20mA`, why? Shouldn't there be still `8.04A` and it is burning up the LEDs, and also why is the first LED not getting burned up by the 9V going into it? I get that voltage is dropped across it. But, it doesn't just ignore the other voltage going through it, or does it? Is this a problem with the program I am using [EveryCircuit](http://everycircuit.com) or is there something I am missing?

Comment: This looks like a very, very crude simulation. I wouldn't trust it for anything. It appears to be adding components and parameters behind the scenes, and not telling you about it. The little arrows for current are also pointing in the wrong direction for conventional current flow.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I purposely have conventional flow off, but do you have a program that you would recommend?

Comment: Since it is free, I will recommend LTspice.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson So, what was EveryCircuit doing wrong? Should there have been ```8.04A``` still. Was the voltage correct?

Comment: A proper simulator should not add a "internal resistance" to an ideal voltage source, nor should it make any assumptions about the resistance of the wire. The designer adds those parasitic values explicitly. Assuming that an LED has a forward voltage of exactly 3V at exactly 20mA also seems contrived and inaccurate.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson So the amperage shouldn't have dropped?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that the results are so untrustworthy that I won't even try to explain them.

Comment: In addition to Elliot's commentary on that terrible simulator, each LED in your circuit only "knows" what the voltage across itself is. It has no way of "knowing" the total supply voltage to the entire circuit. So your 1st LED only "sees" (9-6) = 3v, the 2nd LED "sees" (6-3) = 3v, and the 3rd LED "sees" (3-0) = 3v.

Comment: "*I HAVE ELECTRON FLOW ON INSTEAD OF CONVENTIONAL FLOW ON PURPOSE.* This will only get you confused. Work with conventional current (like everyone else) and the current will flow in the direction of the arrows in your diodes and transistors. You will also be more able to discuss circuits with other engineers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion: Do not believe Every Circuit. The link you gave did not give access to any user's manual nor specs. The program may be visually attractive, but without knowing what it actually does I will not want to use it. As suggested use established programs(see NOTE1) to get some experience. Learn the electricity basics such as Ohm's and Kirchoff's laws and how to use them manually to solve elementary circuits. Software analysis is 100% useless if you don't understand the basic math facts of the electricity.

**About your circuit:**  Without knowing properties of the parts the current is undefined. As said by others, a program which gives some properties to parts without showing them is useless. Start with trying to find the hidden properties of the parts if you want to continue with Every Circuit.

NOTE1: This site has the Circuit Lab which is useful and still hasn't failed on my screen.

Comment: But how can you change forward voltage, or needed amperage or things like that in Circuit Lab?

Comment: You modify the model of the LED. A proper component model, however, doesn't have a field "forward voltage"; that's an emergent property from the (extended) exponential current model of a diode. Anyway, we should really not be discussing anything based on the broken simulator you're using.

Comment: @BeastCoder2 Mathematical circuit laws and the properties of the parts define how the voltages and currents distribute in a circuit. For example if you have exactly 9V battery which keeps 9V with all loads (except zero ohm short circuit) and you connect to it 2 resistors in series, one 1 Ohm and the other 2 Ohms, you get 3A current and the 9V distributes as 6V over the 2 Ohm resistor, 3V over the 1 Ohm resistor. Circuit Lab would solve it in a second. Do not start any circuit analyzing programs before you can get it also manually.

Answer (score 0):

First of all voltage is a relative quantity. It is only defined with reference to some reference point (physicists sometimes use infinity as a reference point, but that isn't of much practical relevance). A component only sees the voltage across it.

We model our components with equations. All models are an approximation of reality and some models are better approximations than others. A circuit simulator is fundamentally a program that takes a pile of equations modeling components and tries to solve them.

We model a resistor as a component where voltage is proportional to current. This is a very good model and nearly always good enough (though for power resistors thermal effects may need to be considered).

LEDs are somewhat trickier things to model. The simplest "lie to to children" model is a component that has a fixed forward voltage whenever current is flowing through it and blocks all current in the reverse direction. This is a poor model, but for many simple circuits it's good enough to reason about the circuit with. Simulators are unlikely to use this model though because discontinuities are problematic to simulate.

A better model is the [Shockley_diode_equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shockley_diode_equation) which gives a roughly exponential relationship between current and voltage.

$$ I=I_\mathrm{S} \left( e^\frac{V_\text{D}}{n V_\text{T}} - 1 \right)$$

That is a pretty good model at low currents, but at high currents it starts to break down as the parasitic resistances become significant. So a better model still will include those parasitic resistances.

The parameters to the diode equation will depend on the type and size of the diode, they also depend heavily on temperature and may vary significantly from one device to the next. For this reason it is generally considered a bad idea to run LEDs off a constant voltage source. With a constant voltage source small variations in supply voltage or LED characteristics can lead to very large variations in current.

It appears to me that your software parameterized it's LED model so that it would have a current of exactly 20ma at 3V. That is within the range of plausible parameters and makes the numbers look nice for the kiddies, but it's not exactly realistic to get nice numbers like that.